# how i can decrease execution time of 3 operation(add in database , notification and broadcast) in the same time with laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, notifications

the idea is when i try to add a new project in database i also send notification email and broadcast a database notification to the other users and this action works but spent a lot of time about 10 seconds that's why i asked you to find a solution in order to decrease the execution time 
my Notification class:

```
  public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','database','broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('New Project :' . $this->data['projet'])
        ->action('Notification Action', url('/detail/'.$this->data['id']))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [

            'idprojet' => $this->data['id'],
            'projet' => $this->data['projet'],
            'typeNotification' =>'App\Notifications\NewProject'
        ];
    }
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
{
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'idprojet' => $this->data['id'],
            'projet' => $this->data['projet'],
            'user' => auth()->user(),
            'typeNotification' =>'App\Notifications\NewProject'
    ]);
}
```

my code in controller

```
     public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //


        $this->validate($request,[

            'name' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'durre' =>  'required|string|max:50',
            'description'=>'required|string|max:5000',
            'client_id' => 'required',
            'budget' => 'required',
              ]);


          $data = $request->all();
           $client = User::where('id', $data['client_id'])->first();
           $projet =new Projet;
            $projet->name = $data['name'];
            $projet->durre = $data['durre'];
            $projet->description = $data['description'];
            $projet->client_id = $data['client_id'];
            $projet->owner = $client->name;
            $projet->budget = $data['budget'];
            $projet->save();
          $ids=[$request->membre_id,$request->chefprojet];
           $chef = User::whereIn('id' , $ids)->get();
    $data = array(
'projet' => $projet->name,
'id' => $projet->id,
    );
          Notification::send( $chef,new NewProject ($data));
       }
```

I also use the laravel pusher to make the notification in real time

any solution please

Comment: Is your notification `Queueable`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No i didn't use Queueable . how i can use it ?

Comment: `<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewProject extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
     
        $this->data=$data;
    }
`